# Doing Ajax request in interceptor

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, angular-http-interceptors

I'm trying to create an interceptor in AngularJS that checks if I'm already logged in or not. It does this by looking at the `$rootScope.user` variable.

If the`$rootScope.user` variable doesn't exist then I want to make an Ajax call to see if there is still a Session alive on the server.

The problem is that I then end up in a infinite loop, because my interceptor is intercepting all my Ajax requests...

I basically have this now:

```
.factory('resourceInterceptor', ['$rootScope', 'AccountService', function($rootScope, accountService) {
    return {
        request: function(request) {
            if(!$rootScope.user) {
                var userData = accountService.getUserSession(); // creates loop
                //var userData = $http.get('api/Account'); // Same thing
            }

            return request;
        }
    }
}]);
```

But this doesn't work, it gives this error:

```
Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $http <- $resource <- AccountService <- resourceInterceptor <- $http <- $compile
```

Or same with $http:

```
Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $http <- resourceInterceptor <- $http <- $compile
```

So how can I then solve this issue? I'd like to do an Ajax request from my interceptor, so I can retrieve the user info from the database.

---

Please note: I know that there a a lot of different, and perhaps better ways, of implementing some sort of authentication method, like using a token in the header. I'm aware of that and I'm ***not*** looking for answers about different, better authentication methods. I'd like to have answers about this specific problem.

Comment: could you also show getUserSession fn  ?

Comment: Just add a check in interceptor to not make call if url equals auth url

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $injector service and acquire $http service using its capabilities.

It will look something like this (example with $http):

```
.factory('resourceInterceptor', ['$rootScope', '$injector', '$q', function($rootScope, $injector, $q) {

    return {
        request: function(config) {

            var $http = $injector.get('$http');

            if(!$rootScope.user) {
                var userData = $http.get('api/Account');
            }

            return config || $q.when(config);
        }
    }
}]);
```

This is known circular dependency problem in case of using $http inside interceptor (each one relies on each other).

---

Example plunkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/7zEuVlHgGNyBbzCg8Lfi?p=preview

This issue and answer on official AngularJS github repository - [link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2367)

Information about $injector from official AngularJS documentation - [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector)

Information about $injector on egghead.io - [link](http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/wyUGYzxeQA/angularjs-injectors)

Comment: Unfortunately this still gives me the same error. I have exactly the same code that you have.

Comment: could you prepare some minimal plunker to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I tried, but I can't get the Plnkr to work. Eventhough it should work... It can't inject `$http` into my factory. So I can't really show a working example. This was as far as I could get with it: http://plnkr.co/edit/AHOek5VDwO8qlBy0Hi1u?p=preview -- Maybe you see what the problem is

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Done mistake in my code, modified the answer. Also edited the plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/7zEuVlHgGNyBbzCg8Lfi?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The technique described [here](http://michalostruszka.pl/blog/2013/09/06/selective_http_errors_handling_in_angularjs/) could probably help you. In the request you make inside of your interceptor you would set the custom property (`bypassErrorsInterceptor`), and the interceptor itself should do the request only in case when `bypassErrorsInterceptor` is not set (that means the request did not originate from inside of the interceptor) - infinite loop avoided!